# < bit half-byte byte ... > memory access in 32-bit memory using verilog

Tags: verilog

This is my synthesizable memory model in Verilog.

```
    module memory(
        output reg [31:0] data_out,
        input [31:0] address,
        input [31:0] data_in, 
        input write_enable,
        input clk
    );
        reg [31:0] memory [0:255];

        always @(posedge clk) begin
            if (write_enable) begin
                memory[address] <= data_in;
            end
            data_out <= memory[address];
        end

    endmodule
```

For example:

`memory[32'h10]` contains `0xAAAAAAAA`

I just want to write one byte of data `0xFF` in memory `address 0x10` so that

`memory[32'h10]` contains `0xFFAAAAAA`

Can you recommend a good way to change my code so that I can access only one bit, half-byte, byte, halfword, or word in my memory module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What 'a good way' is depends on your synthesis target. If it's an FPGA you should consider that bit-wise write access for large memories is generally not a good idea. This will possibly prevent the memory from mapping to RAM resources, dramatically increasing routing costs.

Byte enables are generally directly supported. You can view the Xilinx coding guidelines [here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/xst.pdf) where it describes byte enables on page 159.

Answer (score 2):

1. You only declared 256 words of 32-bits, but your address bus is 32-bits wide, allowing up to 2^32 words of 32-bits. You might want to reduce your address bus width to 8-bits to match the number of words you declared.
2. For Xilinx FPGAs I use the CORE Generator tool to instantiate one or more BlockRAMs of the right width and depth. BlockRAMs have an option to support individual byte enables.
3. This code might work, but I haven't tried it

   ```
   module memory (
       output reg [31:0] data_out,
       input [7:0] address,
       input [31:0] data_in, 
       input [3:0] write_enable,
       input clk
   );

   reg [31:0] memory [0:255];

   reg [31:0] memory_in = 0; // wire reg

   always @* begin : combinational_logic
       memory_in = memory[address];
       if (write_enable[3])
           memory_in[31:24] = data_in[31:24];
       if (write_enable[2])
           memory_in[23:16] = data_in[23:16];
       if (write_enable[1])
           memory_in[15:8] = data_in[15:8];
       if (write_enable[0])
           memory_in[7:0] = data_in[7:0];
   end

   always @(posedge clk) begin : sequential_logic
       if (|write_enable) begin
           memory[address] <= memory_in;
       end
       data_out <= memory[address];
   end
   ```

   endmodule